# Angular 2 set dynamic functions name on element

Tags: function, angular, typescript, dynamic

Hi I try to add dynamic functions name on button  but don't know how to do that try something but doesn't work.

My example

```
<button md-icon-button (click)="on{{scial.name}}()"><i class="{{social.icon}} "></i></button>
```

it's on `*ngFor`

Is it realy to do?

Comment: In general `{{}}` is not supposed to be used together with `[input]` or `(event)`. If you use `[]` or `()` then use `x + 'y'` to concatenate strings in the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` explicitly

```
<button md-icon-button (click)="this['on' + scial.name]()">
```

Comment: it works but give error

EXCEPTION: Error in ./SignUpSocialItem class SignUpSocialItem - inline template:3:4 caused by: self.context.self[("on" + self.context.social.name)] is not a function

Comment: Seems to work without problems for me https://plnkr.co/edit/zENP2iTnlIzwRJqXjvuf?p=preview

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad to hear you could make it work.

Comment: Really, I always thought `this` is not supported in bindings. Only on the phone right now and can't test. Will have a look later.

Comment: Just tried it. `this['on' + 'Foo']()` really works as well. Thanks a lot for the hint.